# Move login controls to home page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, indexing, authentication, html

I would like to have the login interface on my home page for ASP.NET MVC. I have tried creating a partial view inside of the `~/Views/Account/` directory named `LogOn.ascx`. But when I try to submit the values via the submit button, everything blows up. Am I missing something or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Nissan's probably right, but you might want to be a bit more specific than "Everything blows up" - perhaps some examples of the error messages, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that the LogOn form ACTION is to post to the AccountController implicitly.  The reason why it may not work is that it's trying to post to your HomeController since you didn't implicitilty tell it where to go and the main View is from the HomeController.